# Perl Switch Statement

Tags: perl, switch-statement, case, conditional-statements

Is there any way to run a block of code if none of the case blocks were matched? For instance:

```
switch($a) {

  case // {}
  case // {}
  ...
  # DO SOMETHING IF NONE OF THE ABOVE CASES WERE MATCHED
}
```

`else` is not what I'm looking for, since it applies only to the last case block.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's always the switching in Perl 5.10, if you're running it of course.

```
use feature qw(switch);

given($a){
  when(1) { print 'Number one'; }
  when(2) { print 'Number two'; }
  default { print 'Everything else' }
}
```

Comment: Full documentation on the switch feature: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements

Comment: Need to include version number in a "use" statement based on the syntax you want, as well.

Comment: Since Perl 5.18 might want to add `no warnings qw( experimental::smartmatch );`

Comment: This approach is starting to sound hack on hack on hack. As @rustyx said, may wish to add the no warnings. If you do, may also wish to 1) add the ```use warnings qw( experimental::smartmatch );``` 2) also add the perl critic exclusion for the no warnings ```  ## no critic (some_policy) ```

Comment: given is deprecated in (Strawberry) Perl 5 (5.38.2).

Answer (score 12):

Please note that `use Switch` in any form is deprecated as it is being replaced (and removed in the next perl release) by perl's own form of switch statement, which is, as already answered:

```
use feature qw(switch);

given ($x)
{
when ('case1') { print 1; }
default {print 0; }
}
```

Using default case achieves the outcome you want. Also don't forget to use `last` if you want the switch to stop being evaluated after one condition is evaluated true.

Comment: Note that given/when was later deemed experimental. You can, of course, get rid of the warnings by adding a "no warnings 'experimental';" statement. See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/given.html

Answer (score 7):

I usually use the below block construct which is more simple and no need to import anything.

```
SWITCH: {
    if($key =~ /^abc/) { $key = "key starts with abc"; last SWITCH; } # 'last' breaks the 'SWITCH' block
    if($key =~ /^def/) { $key = "key starts with def"; last SWITCH; }
    if($key =~ /^ghi/) { $key = "key starts with ghi"; last SWITCH; }   
    $key = "Default value";
}

print $key;
```

Answer (score 5):

`else` is indeed what you are looking for.

```
switch ( $n ) {
    case 1 { print "one\n" }
    case 2 { print "two\n" }
    else   { print "other\n" }
}
```

The above would output "other" for `$n=3` and "one" for `$n=1`.

Answer (score 4):

This statement return **Case 2**:

```
my $test = 'abcd';

print test($test);

sub test {
    for ($_[0]) {
        /ad/ && return 'Case 1';
        /bc/ && return 'Case 2';
        /c/ && return 'Case 3';
    }
}
```

This one return **Case 3**:

```
my $test = 'abcd';
my $result;

for ($test) {
    /ad/ && do { $result = 'case 1' };
    /bb/ && do { $result = 'case 2' };
    /cd/ && do { $result = 'case 3' };
}

print $result;
```

This one **Case 2**:

```
my $test = 'abcd';
my $result;

for ($test) {
    /ad/ && do { $result = 'case 1'; last };
    /bc/ && do { $result = 'case 2'; last };
    /cd/ && do { $result = 'case 3'; last };
}

print $result;
```

**Default**:

```
my $test = 'abcd';
my $result;

for ($test) {
    /aa/ && do { $result = 'case 1'; last };
    /bb/ && do { $result = 'case 2'; last };
    /cc/ && do { $result = 'case 3'; last };

    $result = 'Default';
}

print $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

> > "else is not what I'm looking for, since it applies only to the last case block."

As long as you are not using fall-through:

```
use Switch 'fallthrough';
```

You are safe.

If you reach the last case statement it means none of the case statements above it matched the criteria. In other words (if there is no fall-through) the else statement is only executed if all case statements fail to satisfy their conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [`use Switch`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html), you can use an `else` clause

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to decide an assignment use the ternary operator `?:`

```
die "Expecting name of the system (reise/synpac/vias) as parameter.\n"
    unless $_ = shift;
@opt{qw/Name Code Id UID/} =
    /^\s*rei(?:se)?\s*$/i   ? qw/ CEP    REI    80 ipcp_rei / :
    /^\s*syn(?:pac)?\s*$/i  ? qw/ SYNPAC SYNPAC 67 ipcp_sym / :
    /^\s*vias?\s*$/i        ? qw/ VIAS   VIAS   68 ipcp_via / :
    do { die "Unknown system ‘$_’.\n"; };   # or default values
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for *feature*.

Is *perlcritic* safe. I have used this with 20+ options after converting from an else-if chain.

```
my $key = 'fruity';  # User chosen value
my %code_ref = (
    apple => sub { print("Apple\n"); },
    pear => sub { my_other_code(); },
    orange => sub { my_still_other_code();  },
);
if ( exists $code_ref{$key} ) {
    $code_ref{$key}->();
}
else { # Default case
    print STDERR "$0: unknown option '$key'\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote and use these three Perl subroutine switches and find them very useful.

```
sub switchOne($){          # standard switch
my($prefix,$testVal,@caseVals)=@_;
$s=0;
    while($s<scalar(@caseVals)){
        if($testVal eq $caseVals->[$s]){
            return $prefix."_".$testVal;
        }
        $s++;
    }
return $prefix."Not";
}

sub switchTwo($){         # test for 2 conditions switch = mapping x & Y
my($prefix,$testVal1,$testVal2,@caseVals1,@caseVals2)=@_;
$s=0;
    while($s<scalar(@caseVals)){
        if($testVal1 eq $caseVals1->[$s] && $testVal2 eq $caseVals2->[$s]){
            return $prefix."_".$testVal1;
        }
        $s++;
    }
return $prefix."Not";
}

sub switchRange($){         # test for range switch
my($prefix,$testVal1,@caseVals1,@caseVals2)=@_;
$s=0;
    while($s<scalar(@caseVals)){
        if($testVal > $caseVals->[$s]&&$testVal < $caseVals2->[$s]){
            return $prefix."_".($s+1);
        }
        $s++;
    }
return $prefix."Not";
}


#############  here is the calling code 
$prefix="case";
@cases=(1,12,3,45,5,61,7,8,9,10);       # cases to test against / quote strings
$case=&switchOne($prefix,$testvariable,\@cases);  

# prefix must be different for each switch call for different labels
#duplicate labels can cause problems

while($case ne ""){
    # initialization common code block

    goto $case;

case_1:                #   cases in array
    #code
    last;

case_12:
     # code
     last;


case_61:
    last;
case_7:
    last;    
case_8:
    last;
case_9:
    last;
case_10:
    last;

caseNot:
     # no match comes here

     #code
     last;
}

#  here is a dbl variable matching call example
# prefix can be in the call quoted
# both cases must be true to get a match

$case=&switchTwo("intrsctn",$test1,$test2,\@cases1,\@cases2);
while($case ne ""){
    # initial code as desired
    goto $case;

intrsctn_1:  
     # code
     last;

# as many labels as cases

intrsctnNot:
    last;
}

# here is a switch example to test for a variable in a range (between)

$case=&switchRange("thscase",$testvariable,\@cases1,\@cases2);
while($case ne ""){

        goto $case;

thscase_1:       # this returns the array index +1 on the prefix
     # code
     last;

# as many labels as cases

thscaseNot:
    # N must be uppercase
    last;
}
```